# How to setup NSUserTrackingUsageDescription in iOS if Facebook App Events enabled?

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk, react-native-fbsdk

My app is configured with Facebook iOS SDK to track App Events. As this provides data to 3rd party (Facebook) I have added the following *NSUserTrackingUsageDescription*

```
<key>NSUserTrackingUsageDescription</key>
<string>ABCD app uses basic data to improve analytics.</string>
```

But the app was rejected from the App Store. As the end goal of the app events is to be used in Ads Manager, I'm now thinking about changing the string into the following. The app is not showing any advertisements for users.

```
<key>NSUserTrackingUsageDescription</key>
<string>ABCD app uses basic data to improve analytics and give a personalized experience.</string>
```

Is this the approach to take?

Comment: The tracking usage description needs to describe its use of the advertising identifier. The advertising identifier should not be used for basic app analytics.

Comment: @Paulw11 yes. Is the updated one okay? or should I need to mention this is for targeting ads via 3rd parties specifically?